# Android: simple webview code. ERR: Unable to start Activity 

Tags: android, android-emulator, webview

I have following code:

```
public class reader extends Activity {

    WebView mWebView;
    String mFilename;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

     }

}
```

When I run this, the emulator shows "Sorry:.. mireader Stopped unexpectedly" error.. Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have `setContentView(R.layout.webview);`? You already call `setContentView` two lines before.

And do you have the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Also, you should attach the logcat output as that'll probably give you a callstack pointing you in the general direction of the problem.

Comment: I 've :<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  i commented this line: //setContentView(R.layout.main); in log cat :FATEL EXCEPTION in main java lang runtime error unable to start activity component info(.....

Comment: assuming windows envt: select(shift+cursor keys), copy(Ctrl+c) and paste(ctrl+v).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call the setContentView function twice. I am guessing your onCreate method should look like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i am suggesting you to do it again
create a simple project.paste the following code your main.xml

android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />

and in the manifest file put the line just before ending the

and run.I think nothing wrong with it.Remove your second setContView...

Answer (score 0):

go to this link you can easily create your webview application.....

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

add this in between your setcontentView and loadurl method

mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);